# Converting image to base64 results in empty image

Tags: java, image

I am using below code to convert base64 data to png image using java code but it always results in empty image. If i use the same base64 data to image in online services it works fine, below is the code, is there any issue with this code?

```
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(imageInBase64);
    System.out.println("Writing steam... " + data);
    try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\test.png"))) {
        stream.write(data);
    }
    System.out.println("Converted..");
```

Comment: Did you close the stream?

Comment: I am using new try{} statement in java 7 right? wouldn't that close automatically?

Comment: @EvanKnowles: The try-with-resources statement will do that.

Comment: Ah, my bad, hadn't noticed where it was declared.

Comment: So what does `imageInBase64` look like? Does *anything* get written to the file? What exactly do you mean by "empty image"? How are you checking that?

Comment: If I give that base64 image in some online tools it works perfectly, so this mean base64 data is not wrong right?

Comment: What does `System.out.println("Writing steam... " + data.length);` yield?

Comment: It prints some thing like H@47347

Comment: @HannoBinder asked about data.length, not data. Your title should probably be "Converting _from_"... Can you include an example base64 image you are trying to decode in your question? That would allow others to test it. EDIT: It _is_ a PNG file, right?